# UART in LPC1778 not working

Tags: microcontroller, uart, keil, interfacing, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to send a byte using `UART1` in `LPC1778` (I'm Using Keil Simulator).

However I'm not able to send the byte; after detailed debugging, I came to the conclusion that data is not getting written in the `UART1->THR` register.

This is the code snipped for transmission:

```
void uart1_tra(uint8_t x)
{
    LPC_UART1->THR=x;
    //after this line ,irrespective of the value of x, UART1->THR remains at a 
    VALUE EQUAL TO 0         

    while(1)
    {
        if(LPC_UART1->LSR&(1<<5))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Initialization code:

```
void uar1_init(void) 
{
    LPC_SC->PCONP|=1u<<4; 
    LPC_SC->PCLKSEL|=1U; 
    LPC_UART1->LCR|=1U<<7; 
    LPC_UART1->DLL|=0x05; //SET SOME BAUD RATE 
    LPC_UART1->FDR|= 0x21; //END OF BAUD RATE CALCULATIONS
    LPC_UART1->LCR&=~(1U<<7);//DISABLE DLAB 
    LPC_UART1->LCR|=3U;//8-BITCHARACTER LENGTH 
    LPC_UART1->FCR|=1U; //ENABLE FIFO REG 
    LPC_UART1->FCR|=(0X03<<1);//RESET RXBUFFERS 
    //LPC_UART1->IER|=3u;//to ENABLE INTERRUPTS 
    LPC_IOCON->P0_15|=1U; 
    LPC_IOCON->P0_16|=1; 
}
```

Comment: you have properly initialized the uart before getting to this point?  does the scope show the character going out of the chip?

Comment: Yes i have , i will atatch the code below ,please have a look.

Comment: Yes i have , i will attatch the code below ,please have a look.void uar1_init(void)
   {
   LPC_SC->PCONP|=1u<<4;
   
   LPC_SC->PCLKSEL|=1U;
   LPC_UART1->LCR|=1U<<7;
   LPC_UART1->DLL|=0x05; //SET SOME BAUD RATE
   
   LPC_UART1->FDR|= 0x21;
   //END OF BAUD RATE CALCULATIONS
   LPC_UART1->LCR&=~(1U<<7);//DISABLE DLAB
   LPC_UART1->LCR|=3U;//8-BITCHARACTER LENGTH
   LPC_UART1->FCR|=1U;
   //ENABLE FIFO REG
   LPC_UART1->FCR|=(0X03<<1);//RESET RXBUFFERS
   //LPC_UART1->IER|=3u;//to ENABLE INTERRUPTS
   LPC_IOCON->P0_15|=1U;
   LPC_IOCON->P0_16|=1;
   }

Comment: First, THR register is write only (see user manual for your MCU). Second, try to run this code in real hardware. Unfortunately, simulator has numerous errors...

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexey, tried the same code in the hardware, it is sending and receiving data.